# Tire pressure sensor doesn't read

Tags: brakes, sensor, pressure

I work on several makes and models, and found that after replacing brake pads that the "low tire pressure" warning comes on as a sensor fault. Is there something I'm hitting that causes this? How can I prevent the issue?

Comment: Some tire pressure sensors are not in the tire, but part of the anti-lock brake system. The wheel speed sensor is used to track the rotation of the tire. When it becomes out of sync with the other three, it shows on the dash as a low tire indication (I don't know what the differential has to be to register, though I bet it is manufacturer dependent). What I'm thinking is you might have upset the sensor somehow which caused the light to come on. Don't know this for a fact so leaving as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Some tire pressure sensors are not in the tire, but part of the anti-lock brake system. The wheel speed sensor is used to track the rotation of the tire. When it becomes out of sync with the other three, it shows on the dash as a low tire indication (I don't know what the differential has to be to register, though I bet it is manufacturer dependent). What I'm thinking is you might have upset the sensor somehow which caused the light to come on.